# how to change only textual part of a div keeping checkbox as is

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
$('.title').text('ipsum');
});
```

```css
.button{
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'><input class='checka' type='checkbox'>lorem</div>
</br>
<div class='button'>CLICK</div>
```

You can see that `checkbox` is deleted.

How to change only text on `title` i.e. keeping a checkbox (checked or not) as is?

Comment: One way is determin all children nodes and look for node type which is represented as text node.

Comment: You can't do both one of the easiest way is to create a label inside the div and set the value whenever you want to change. Hope it solves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so (assuming you are Ok adding a span around the text. This allows you to target the span instead.

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
$('.title span').text('ipsum');
});
```

```css
.button{
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'><input class='checka' type='checkbox'><span>lorem</span></div>
</br>
<div class='button'>CLICK</div>
```

You can make this work with any other html element really, it doesn't have to be a span as long as you have something you can target using a selector.

**Note**: Aspointed out in the comments you might be better off using a label for this instead of a span as this is the correct element to accompany a form element. Your label would look something like:

```
<label for="myCheckboxIdHere">lorem<label>
```

and your selector would just change to `.title label`

Comment: I think its better to use **label** instead of **span**.

Comment: You're right as the label is the correct element to use for a form element but the answer was to provide the concept. I'll edit so it's clear thought.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Not best way but one of the option with your current code is to Replace the `$('.title').html()` with new `html()`:

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
$('.title').html($('.title').html().replace('lorem','ipsum'));
});
```

```css
.button{
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'><input class='checka' type='checkbox'>lorem</div>
</br>
<div class='button'>CLICK</div>
```

**2.** Correct way is to use `<label for="checkbox_id">Text</label>`

> The `<label>` element is one of a handful of elements that only exists and makes sense in relationship to another element.
>
> For a  to to associate with another element , it must include a `for attribute`, which identifies the `<input>` to which it is associated. The `for attribute's` value should match the id (not the name) of the `<input>` element.

[Read more](https://html.com/tags/label/#ixzz5OR2aOxbm)

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
$('.title label').text('ipsum');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'><input class='checka' id="checka" type='checkbox'><label for="checka">lorem</label></div>
</br>
<div class='button'>CLICK</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) with your `input` to make this work.

Look at the following code:

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  $('.checkbox-label').text('ipsum');
});
```

```css
.button {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>
  <input id="check" type='checkbox'>
  <label for="check" class='checkbox-label'>lorem</label>
</div>
<br>
<div class='button'>CLICK</div>
```

Comment: Added the `for` attribute, but a label can be added to an input nonetheless

Answer (score -1):

just give span class to the text element you want to change

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
$('.changeble_text').text('ipsum');
});
```

```css
.button{
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>
 <input class='checka' type='checkbox'>
 <span class="changeble_text">lorem</span>
   </div>
</br>
<div class='button'>CLICK</div>
```